# Problems in creating desired phylogenetic tree with ggtree

Tags: r, bioconductor, phylogenetics, phylogeny

I am working on haplotype data and want to make a tree out of haplogroups using **ggtree**. I have following data in **newick format**.

```
(B(B2b_M112),C(C_RPS4Y711,C1a_V20,C2_M217,C2b1a_F3985,C2C1_Z1338),E(E1b1a_V38,E1b1b_M215,E2_M75),G(G_M201,G1_M342,G2a1_Z6552,G2a2a_PF3147,G2a2b2b_PF3359,G2a2b1_M406,G2a2b2a1a_U1,G2a2b2a1b_L497,G2a2b2a1c_CTS342,G2a_L30,G2b_M3155,G2b_M283),H(H1_M69,H1a_M82),I(I_M170,I1_M253,I2a1_Isles,I2a1_S21825,I2a1a_M26,I2a1b3_L621,I2a2a_M223,I2a2b_L38,I2c2_Y16419),J(J_M304,J1a_PF7257,J1a2a1a2_P58,J1a2a2_PF7264,J1a3_Z1828,J2_M172,J2a_L25,J2a1_L26,J2a1_M319,J2a1_Z1846,J2a1_Z387,J2a1_Z467,J2a1_Z6046,J2a1_Z6063,J2a1_Z6065,J2a1_Z7671,J2a1_Z7700,J2a2_PF5008, J2b_M241,J2b1_M205,J2b2_M241,J2b2_Z2456),K(K_M9),L(L_M20,L1_M22,L1a_M27,L1b_M317,L1c_M357),N(N3,N1a1_M46,N1a2_L666),O(O1a1_B384,O1b1_F2320,O1b2_P49,O2 IMS_JST0213554,O2a1_F51,O_O2a2_F525,O3_M122),Q(Q F1096,Q_L27,Q_L56,Q_M24,Q_M346),R(R_M207,M734,P224,P280xM173,R1a_M417,R1a1_M459,R1a1a_M17,R1b_M343,R1b_M73,R1b1a1b_V1636,R1b1a2_V88,R1b1b_PH155,R2_M479,R2a_M124),T(T_M184,T_L131,T_PF5633));
```

I am using following R code to plot a tree from this data,

```
> library("ggtree")
> tree <- read.tree(text = "(B(B2b_M112),C(C_RPS4Y711,C1a_V20,C2_M217,C2b1a_F3985,C2C1_Z1338),E(E1b1a_V38,E1b1b_M215,E2_M75),G(G_M201,G1_M342,G2a1_Z6552,G2a2a_PF3147,G2a2b2b_PF3359,G2a2b1_M406,G2a2b2a1a_U1,G2a2b2a1b_L497,G2a2b2a1c_CTS342,G2a_L30,G2b_M3155,G2b_M283),H(H1_M69,H1a_M82),I(I_M170,I1_M253,I2a1_Isles,I2a1_S21825,I2a1a_M26,I2a1b3_L621,I2a2a_M223,I2a2b_L38,I2c2_Y16419),J(J_M304,J1a_PF7257,J1a2a1a2_P58,J1a2a2_PF7264,J1a3_Z1828,J2_M172,J2a_L25,J2a1_L26,J2a1_M319,J2a1_Z1846,J2a1_Z387,J2a1_Z467,J2a1_Z6046,J2a1_Z6063,J2a1_Z6065,J2a1_Z7671,J2a1_Z7700,J2a2_PF5008, J2b_M241,J2b1_M205,J2b2_M241,J2b2_Z2456),K(K_M9),L(L_M20,L1_M22,L1a_M27,L1b_M317,L1c_M357),N(N3,N1a1_M46,N1a2_L666),O(O1a1_B384,O1b1_F2320,O1b2_P49,O2 IMS_JST0213554,O2a1_F51,O_O2a2_F525,O3_M122),Q(Q F1096,Q_L27,Q_L56,Q_M24,Q_M346),R(R_M207,M734,P224,P280xM173,R1a_M417,R1a1_M459,R1a1a_M17,R1b_M343,R1b_M73,R1b1a1b_V1636,R1b1a2_V88,R1b1b_PH155,R2_M479,R2a_M124),T(T_M184,T_L131,T_PF5633));")
> p<-ggtree(tree)
> p+geom_tiplab()
```

And the displayed tree looks like this 
[image]

I have following problems in this tree,

1. It gives a low quality image
2. It does not show the haplotype taxa names clearly
3. I want to arrange haplogroups i.e nodes in the desired according to the tree given below,

[image]

i.e B haplogroups with C haplotypes and with C, E named haplotypes etc.

I have tried to solve these problems but failed to find any solution. Is there a solution?

Comment: for the `tiplab` issue, pls refer to the [FAQ](https://guangchuangyu.github.io/software/ggtree/faq/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above given problems were solved using manual tree construction through [MEGA](http://www.megasoftware.net/). MEGA allows manual construction/manipulation of trees. The newick format obtained after manually constructing the desired tree using MEGA is:

```
((((((((((((T_M184,T_L131,T_PF5633),T),((R_M207,M734,P224,P280xM173,R1a_M417,R1a1_M459,R1a1a_M17,R1b_M343,R1b_M73,R1b1a1b_V1636,R1b1a2_V88,R1b1b_PH155,R2_M479,R2a_M124),R)),((Q F1096,Q_L27,Q_L56,Q_M24,Q_M346),Q)),(((((((O1a1_B384,O1b1_F2320),O1b2_P49),O2IMS_JST0213554),O2a1_F51),O_O2a2_F525),O3_M122),O)),(((N3,N1a1_M46),N1a2_L666),N)),(((((L_M20,L1_M22),L1a_M27),L1b_M317),L1c_M357),L)),(K,K_M9)),((((((((((((((((((((((J_M304,J1a_PF7257),J1a2a1a2_P58),J1a2a2_PF7264),J1a3_Z1828),J2_M172),J2a_L25),J2a1_L26),J2a1_M319),J2a1_Z1846),J2a1_Z387),J2a1_Z467),J2a1_Z6046),J2a1_Z6063),J2a1_Z6065),J2a1_Z7671),J2a1_Z7700),J2a2_PF5008),J2b_M241),J2b1_M205),J2b2_M241),J2b2_Z2456),J)),(((((((((((I_M170,I1_M253),I2a1_Isles),I2a1_S21825),I2a1a_M26),I2a1b3_L621),I2a2a_M223),I2a2b_L38),I2c2_Y16419),I),((H1_M69,H1a_M82),H)),((((((((((((G_M201,G1_M342),G2a1_Z6552),G2a2a_PF3147),G2a2b2b_PF3359),G2a2b1_M406),G2a2b2a1a_U1),G2a2b2a1b_L497),G2a2b2a1c_CTS342),G2a_L30),G2b_M3155),G2b_M283),G))),((E1b1a_V38,E1b1b_M215),(E2_M75,E))),(((((((C_RPS4Y711,C1a_V20),C2_M217),C2b1a_F3985),C2C1_Z1338),C),B2b_M112),B));
```